# Child object with parent's data

Tags: php, class, oop

How create child object, with filled data from parent.

```
<?php

class parentClass{

  public $var;

  private function somefunc(){
    //something
  }
}


class childClass extends parentClass{

  //something here

}


$parent=new parentClass();
$parent->var=SOMETHING;


//need
$child=new childClass();
```

I want from $child  having $child->var WITH FILLED DATA FROM PARENT

Comment: It's not possible. Why do you need this?

Comment: studying classes

Comment: `$parent` is __instance of class__. `$child` is __instance of another class__. Instances know nothing about each other.

Comment: There are **static** variables which refer to class instead object, but it's global scope data. Your question in OOP context means you're trying to fix consequences of earlier misconception (XY problem) - that is, you shouldn't need it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as mentioned in comments, you should not need to do this, but you can achieve it somehow

```
<?php

class P {
    public $v;
}

class C extends P {
    public function __construct(P $p) {
        foreach (get_object_vars($p) as $k=>$v) {
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}

$p = new P();
$p->v = 1;
$c = new C($p);
var_dump($c);
```